# spiral gradient data - change colour

Tags: javascript, html, image, gradient, loader

does anybody know how to change the spiral gradient data of this percentage loader http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/ in order to change the colours of the gradient? For example instead of from orange to green I want from blue to red or whatever.
I already created an issue on bitbucket:). but I never got an answer. I saw the outer and inner ring specification in the js-code in order to change the rest of the loader, but for the percentage spiral its "imgdata" that provides the colour. Could it be that it is a picture described as a bitcode?how can you create something like that?

Here is the example code. The imgdata code is acutally very long but I cut it, because its only numbers and characters:

```
/* Our spiral gradient data */
 var imgdata = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAIAAABMXPacAA[...]ZKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
 gradient = new Image();
 gradient.src = imgdata;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an reply of the coder:

https://bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader/issue/8/spiral-gradient-data

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is hardcoded in the jQuery plug-in (look for "/* Create our linear gradient for the outer ring */" in this file : http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/loader/jquery.percentageloader-01a.js), and i don't see any options to set them on plug-in initialization (or even on runtime).

So the only way to change them is to modify javascript source (Author uses BSD license, so you're allowed to make modifications). As a notice, the project is hosted on bitBucket, and there's already an issue for gradient modifications : https://bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: hey thx, yeah I created that issue on bitbucket:). but I never got an answer. and yeah I saw the outer and inner ring specification in order to change the rest of the loader, but for the percentage spiral its "imgdata" that provides the colour. Could it be that it is a picture described as a bitcode?how can you create something like that?

Comment: Ok, that's your issue, ah ah :D Anyway, to convert an image to base64, you must use toDataURL() in a canvas context (more info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement). The author used an encoded image for conveniance, but you can use a regular image instead and assign its path to gradient.src

Comment: ok thx do you know how i can use a regular image? i tried it with imgdata="test.png" and "data:image/png;test.png". did not work

Comment: imgdata="test.png" should work, the path is maybe relative to the js script ?

Comment: Double-check your path, cause it's supposed to work this way. Here's a fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/Akaryatrh/8gf6X/